# JavaFX TableView Column CheckBox listener

Tags: javafx

I have TableColumn with CheckBox. I have to do this listener and I wonder why the listener doubles after every click.

```
    selectedColumn.setCellFactory(column -> new CheckBoxTableCell<>());
    selectedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> {
        Dir dir = cellData.getValue();
        BooleanProperty property = dir.isSelectedProperty();

        property.addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) ->{
            System.out.println(newValue);
        });

        return property;
    });
```

First click in checkbox i row return:
True
True

Second unselect return:
False
False
False
False

Thrid select return:
True
True
True
True
True
True

why ? :)

Comment: Where does this block of codes resides at? At least show the whole method.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and act accordingly.

Comment: in initialize method

Comment: @Light why would you do this? This wouldn't be the right way to listen its change.

Comment: @Sunflame, There are many ways, I do not think this one is wrong if it works. Well not quite, but your suggestion does not work either. And I'm sorry, you did not offer anything new. You just wrote it is bad and that's it.

Comment: @Light once I have asked you why would you do this. If I would know then I can suggest a solution. Tell me what would you achieve by listening its change.

Comment: @Sunflame it's pretty obvious that the change in the control will do update in beans. And then everything else.

Comment: How many listeners are added here? Check before adding listener that you are not adding it again. That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because controls like `TableView` (and `ListView` etc) virtualizes its contents. From TableView Javadoc:

> The TableView control is designed to **visualize an unlimited number of
>   rows of data**, broken out into columns.

The `TableView` may hold a large number of items. However, on the screen, you could probably see 10-30 rows (each corresponding to a single item) at any point in time.

Without virtualization, if you have 1 million items, it would create 1 million `TableRow` objects (we haven't talked about `TableCell`), with each `TableRow` maintaining all the states/values. This takes *a lot* of memory and processing power.

On the other hand, with virtualization, if your View can only display 10 rows, `TableView` will only create, for example, 12 `TableRow` instances. As you scroll through the list, some of the items disappear from your sight. These `TableRow` instances are immediately reused for items that enters your sight.

This is why `setCellFactory()` and `setCellValueFactory()` methods are of `Callback` type. Each time a row was reused, it will call this callback object to update the `TableCell`. This is why your listener is being added repeatedly, causing this.

Depending on what you need, it may be possible to add a `ListChangedListener` to the list of items.

```
ObservableList<Dir> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(item -> new javafx.beans.Observable[] {item.isSelectedProperty()});
list.addAll(DirList.getDirList());
dirList.setItems(list);

list.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Dir>() {
    @Override public void onChanged(javafx.collections.ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Dir> c) {
        while (c.next()) {
            if (c.wasUpdated()) {
                // Do something
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you have a model named `Dir` with a `BooleanProperty` named `selected`

You can simply let the `cellValueFactory` just:

`selectedColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().isSelectedProperty());`

This would update the model's property if you check/un-check the `CheckBox` in the table cell.

If you use this selected/deselected state of the checkbox, you can use the model, and add the listener there, you will get the same result. Then the listener will be added just once.

You should have instances of `Dir` created then you can do the following for ex. in `initialize`:

```
dir1.selectedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            dir2.selectedProperty().set(oldValue);
        });
```

Or anything you want, then you are sure that the listener is added just once.
As @Jai mentioned, the cell data is used many time and every time the `CallBack` is called, the listener is added to the property, so don't use it inside that method if you want to avoid adding the listener many times to the property.